# Converting set of parameterized types to a map

Tags: scala

Can someone maybe explain to me why I get a compiler error below and the best way to do this type of conversion

Thanks
Des

```
case class A[T](i: Int, x: T)
val set: Set[A[_]] = Set(A(1, 'x'), A(2, 3))
val map: Map[Int, A[_]] = set.map(a => a.i -> a)

type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.Set[(Int, A[_$19]) forSome { type _$19 }] required: Map[Int,A[_]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things here, first I suppose that `A` is a case class (otherwise you would need to use the `new` keyword), second your map returns a `Set` of tuples (not a `Map`), third you are returning a `A[_]` in the map, but `a.x` returns an `Any`, not an `A`:

```
scala> case class A[T](i: Int, x: T)
defined class A

scala> val set: Set[A[_]] = Set(A(1, 'x'), A(2, 3))
set: Set[A[_]] = Set(A(1,x), A(2,3))
```

To match the type signature you can use `toMap` and change `Map[Int, A[_]]` to `Map[Int, _]`

```
scala> val map: Map[Int, _] = set.map(a => a.i -> a.x).toMap
map: Map[Int, _] = Map(1 -> x, 2 -> 3)
```

If you want to keep the original signature (`Map[Int, A[_]]`) you need to return an `A` in the tuple:

```
scala> val map: Map[Int, A[_]] = set.map(a => a.i -> a).toMap
map: Map[Int,A[_]] = Map(1 -> A(1,x), 2 -> A(2,3))
```